# Not able to print after upgrade to 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, printing

I performed a "do-release-upgrade" a few days ago from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. After the upgrade I wasn't able to print. Printing worked before the upgrade.

Printer: Brother MFC-J625DW (connected via WiFi with static IP address 10.0.0.3)
Computer: Lenovo ThinkPad T410 (connected to same network as printer; pinged for confirmation)

When I print a test page, the system notifies me that the job was submitted and completed, but the printer doesn't do anything.

I have looked through logs, but I don't really know which messages are pertinent to the situation.

I've managed to fix this problem with past upgrades, but I'm stumped by this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question in case it helps anyone.

I found this thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2404947 and did an autoremove, upgrade, and reboot. I logged back in and successfully printed a test page.